# Ogr2Ogr appending duplicate records (2X Times) to PostgreSQL Table

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, ogr, osgeo

I'm synchronizing data from AmigoCloud's table with a PostgreSQL table.

I'm using GDAL's ogr2ogr module in osgeo environment. The command I'm running is as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=`my_db_name` user=`my_user` password=`my_password` host=localhost port=5432" "AmigoCloud:`project_id` datasets=`dataset_id`" AMIGOCLOUD_API_KEY `my_api_key` -nln `my_schema.my_table`
```

The issue is that my table from AmigoCloud contains 3620 rows but when they are copied to local postgres through this command, it copies it twice and I get duplicated rows (7240 in total). How to prevent this?

I tried doing `-lco FID=amigo_id` as amigo_id column contains unique values (varchar) but ogr forcefully converts them to integer and gives the error:

"ERROR 1: Wrong field type for amigo_id"

Answer (score 3):

Switch `-append` is adding new features into the table. If you already had a table with 3620 rows then the result is expected. If the table was empty then the result is strange.

If you want to replace the contents of the table use the config option OGR_TRUNCATE https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

> OGR_TRUNCATE: If set to “YES”, the content of the table will be first
> erased with the SQL TRUNCATE command before inserting the first
> feature. This is an alternative to using the -overwrite flag of
> ogr2ogr, that avoids views based on the table to be destroyed. Typical
> use case: ogr2ogr -append PG:dbname=foo abc.shp --config OGR_TRUNCATE
> YES.

Comment: I don't have any existing data, it is running twice for some reason. I tried using `--config OGR_TRUNCATE YES` but it still creates duplicate records.

Comment: What number of features do you get with ogrinfo from amigocloud?

Comment: I get the Feature Count as 3620

Comment: Add `--debug on` into your original command, maybe you get a hint about what happens.